# Display price tax

Tags: products

On the product page i need display also price with tax 19 percent, how i can do it better? How to calculate the correct? Need show basic price and price with tax, now i can display only basic product price, tax is zero, or if i add code: currency($_finalPriceInclTax-$_finalPrice, true, false?> working but not correct

help me how corrected display? Need basic price + 19% = price with tax and display in product page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See As per My suggestion you did not need to change the price.phtml file for as per your custom calculation.

**Step 1:** Magento itself Provide tax setup as per country so you can Manage Tax form `Sales >> Tax >> Manage Tax Rules`. You can read This [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-tax-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them)

**Step 2:** If tax is done then Open your Product `Catalog >> Manage product`. and in price tab select Tax 19%.

**Step 3:** Magento Provide Functionality like display price options like `Including price, Excluding price, Including & Excluding Price` at `catalog level,cart Level` etc.
If you want to set this Options then go to `System >> Configuration >> TAX`. Check the below Image.

[image]

**Step 4:** Based on that Magento Automatically Display price in frontend Side.

Let me know if any comments.